# update post meta not working when called from updated_post_meta hook

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, post-meta

I am adding (insert) into a non-Wp table soon after a specific post meta is updated this part works fine but when on the same function I try to update an another meta of the same post with the inserted ID of non-wp table. Post meta does not update.

I tried `update_post_meta` custom update Query using `wp_query`

I am attaching my code below, please help me.

```
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'user_vid_update', 10, 4 );

function user_vid_update($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) {
if (strpos($meta_key,'video_code') !==false){
 global $wpdb;

 $half_key=strchr($meta_key,"video_code",true);
 $title=$half_key.'video_title';
 $vid_key=$half_key.'vmdbid';
$result = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->vimeography_gallery, array( 'title' =>  $vid_key, 'date_created' => current_time('mysql'),  'is_active' => 1 ) );

$s_url='https://vimeo.com/album/'.$_meta_value;
$r_url='/album/'.$_meta_value;
$gallery_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
$allery_id=$gallery_id;

  $result = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->vimeography_gallery_meta, array(
                          'gallery_id'     => $gallery_id,
                          'source_url'     => $s_url,
                          'resource_uri'   => $r_url,
                          'featured_video' => NULL,
                          'gallery_width'  => NULL,
                          'video_limit'    => 25,
                          'cache_timeout'  => 3600,
                          'theme_name'     => 'bugsauce' ) );




update_post_meta($object_id, $vid_key,$allery_id);



 }

     return true;

 }
```

When I `echo "update_post_meta($object_id, $vid_key,$allery_id);";` I get values from all the variable and if i run this seperately post meta updates.

I am using Advance custom filed repeater to create fields that's why i am creating meta key's dynamic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Deepti, in your example there seems to be a typo where you use `$allery_id` instead of `$gallery_id`

Comment: No, i have assigned the value see this line $allery_id=$gallery_id;